# CSS 3 - Blur effect overlay modal background

Tags: jquery, html, css, modal-dialog, blur

Why when applying CSS3 blur() on a div background, it does not work?

Blur only inside of content and I need blur "background-overlay-div", including top bar and buttons on background, see:

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Igaojsfiddle/jkq2eqxm/2/)

```
.cd-user-modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(52, 54, 66, 0.9);
  z-index: 3;
  overflow-y: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s, visibility 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s, visibility 0.3s;
  transition: opacity 0.3s, visibility 0.3s;
  -webkit-filter: blur(1.5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(1.5px);
  -o-filter: blur(1.5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(1.5px);
  filter: blur(1.5px);
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you trying to blur the background and not the modal?

Comment: @Alain Nisam Yes... blur background not modal content!

Answer (score 1):

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #006600;
  margin: 0%;  
}
 
.bg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/PfXAyaG.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-filter: blur(4px); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  filter: blur(4px);
}

#content {
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;  
}
```

```html
<div class="bg"></div>
<div id="content"><h1>- Hello, world.</h1></div>
```

Comment: Your HTML not this the same structure we have in jsFiddle, so it is possible to do also, but now is not the right answer! Thanks for your time.